# Compatible fonts for English/Spanish translation

Tags: fonts

I am using text for a printed document that will have English and then Spanish translation of the English.  What is the best font combination?

Comment: What do you mean with "best font combination"? What do you want to show with different fonts? Please explain!

Answer (score 1):

When I am not sure about the languages that font supports I go to [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and there you can see all languages that those free fonts support.

My recommendations are:

1. Source Sans Pro
2. Fira Sans
3. PT Sans

You can follow this link and it will give you the list of fonts that support Spanish
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/spanish